# Change of textarea in a table generated by React not working properly

Tags: reactjs

I've prepared a small demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mKxPaB?editors=0010.

```jsx
class List extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      rows: [{ text: "first" }, { text: "second" }]
    };

    this.addNewRow = this.addNewRow.bind(this);
  }

  renderTableRow(t, index) {
    return <Row key={index} {...t} />;
  }

  addNewRow() {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const rowsCopy = prevState.rows.slice();
      return { rows: [{ text: "NOTHING" }].concat(rowsCopy) };
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            {this.state.rows.map((t, i) => this.renderTableRow(t, i))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <button onClick={this.addNewRow}>Add new first row</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Row extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      //it's not working either
      //text: props.text
    };
  }

  render() {
    //if its "value" (instead of defaultValue), text area cannot be edited. When the onChange event is implemented, the same issue appears again
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>
          <textarea defaultValue={this.props.text} />
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
}

// ========================================

ReactDOM.render(<List />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

I want to dynamically add rows to the beginning of a table that should be editable. In my opinion, this solution should work but the table is showing row values in a wrong way (the last row text is duplicated and no "NOTHING" text is displayed). Using a "value props" + "onChange event" approach does not help. Can you help me with that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are using array indices as the keys. At first your **first** row has key of 0 and **second** has key of 1. When you add **NOTHING**, it gets the key of 0, **first** gets 1, and **second** gets 2. Since you are using **defaultValue**, the value in the row (with key 0) doesn't get updated with the updated text props because it already had "first" text as default. It works if you assign a random value (some unique value) as the keys instead of indices `return <Row key={Math.random()} {...t} />;` (I don't recommend Math.random, I am just demonstrating that it works).

ALSO (without changing List component)

We can make it work with **value** and **onChange**. We just need to update the state of **val** in **Row** if the component receives a different text value.
Like so ( Inside **Row** )

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { val: props.text };
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if(nextProps.text !== this.props.text){
         this.setState({ val: nextProps.text })
    }
}

render(){
    ....
    <textarea value={this.state.val} onChange={({target}) => this.setState({ val: target.value })} />
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and second solution!